# My rating button works on its own but when i duplicate it, it doesn't work

Tags: html, css

when I select a rating, it will stay "lit up" but when i duplicate it and give it a different class, when I select a rating on the second copy, it changes the first copy and the second copy doesn't get updated. its hard to explain what happens in text and its better to run it and see it for yourself

```css
.price>div {
  float: left;
  height: 46px;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.price>div:not(:checked)>input {
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
}

.price>div:not(:checked)>label {
  float: right;
  width: 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 30px;
  content: url(../images/shark\ unselected.png);
}

.price>div:not(:checked)>label:before {
  content: url(../images/shark\ unselected.png);
}

.price>div>input:checked~label {
  content: url(../images/shark.png);
}

.price>div:not(:checked)>label:hover,
.price>div:not(:checked)>label:hover~label {
  content: url(../images/shark.png);
}

.price>div>input:checked+label:hover,
.price>div>input:checked+label:hover~label,
.price>div>input:checked~label:hover,
.price>div>input:checked~label:hover~label,
.price>div>label:hover~input:checked~label {
  content: url(../images/shark.png);
}

.taste>div {
  float: left;
  height: 46px;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.taste>div:not(:checked)>input {
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
}

.taste>div:not(:checked)>label {
  float: right;
  width: 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 30px;
  content: url(../images/price-tag\ unselected.png);
}

.taste>div:not(:checked)>label:before {
  content: url(../images/price-tag\ unselected.png);
}

.taste>div>input:checked~label {
  content: url(../images/price-tag.png);
}

.taste>div:not(:checked)>label:hover,
.taste>div:not(:checked)>label:hover~label {
  content: url(../images/price-tag.png);
}

.taste>div>input:checked+label:hover,
.taste>div>input:checked+label:hover~label,
.taste>div>input:checked~label:hover,
.taste>div>input:checked~label:hover~label,
.taste>div>label:hover~input:checked~label {
  content: url(../images/price-tag.png);
}
```

```html
<div class="price d-inline-block w-100">
  <h3>Price</h3>
  <div class="d-inline-block">
    <input type="radio" id="star5" name="price" value="5" />
    <label for="star5" title="text">5 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star4" name="price" value="4" />
    <label for="star4" title="text">4 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star3" name="price" value="3" />
    <label for="star3" title="text">3 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star2" name="price" value="2" />
    <label for="star2" title="text">2 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star1" name="price" value="1" />
    <label for="star1" title="text">1 star</label>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="taste d-inline-block w-100">
  <h3>Taste</h3>
  <div class="d-inline-block">
    <input type="radio" id="star5" name="taste" value="5" />
    <label for="star5" title="text">5 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star4" name="taste" value="4" />
    <label for="star4" title="text">4 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star3" name="taste" value="3" />
    <label for="star3" title="text">3 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star2" name="taste" value="2" />
    <label for="star2" title="text">2 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star1" name="taste" value="1" />
    <label for="star1" title="text">1 star</label>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We would like to help you with your issue but it is difficult for us to replicate this issue because your inputs reference images that we cannot see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont repeat ID, its unique element. It wouldnt work if you duplicate it. Rename second buttons ID and for.

```
  <h3>Taste</h3>
  <div class="d-inline-block">
    <input type="radio" id="star5-2" name="taste" value="5" />
    <label for="star5-2" title="text">5 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star4-2" name="taste" value="4" />
    <label for="star4-2" title="text">4 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star3-2" name="taste" value="3" />
    <label for="star3-2" title="text">3 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star2-2" name="taste" value="2" />
    <label for="star2-2" title="text">2 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star1-2" name="taste" value="1" />
    <label for="star1-2" title="text">1 star</label>
  </div>
```